# Can a Google Form direct to a page according to the response of multiple questions?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

Can a Google Form direct to a page according to how the user responds to multiple questions?

For Example:

Page 1
Question 1 has a response of A or B
Question 2 has a response of 1 or 2

If the person responds A,1 they would move to page 2.
If the person responds B,1 they would move to page 3.
If the person responds A,2 they would move to page 4, and
If the person responds B,2 they would move to page 5.

Comment: Well I'd assume this has been answered before. So you show limited research with your current post.

Comment: I do not see it.  Would you like to show me?

Comment: [Here's](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) a post from Google about it.

Comment: That's not even close to helping with what I'm trying to do. And that post is not on Stack Overflow like you insinuated.  If you can help please help. If not, there's no reason to question my searching skills.

Comment: As I stated I _assumed_ its been answered. I never insinuated that it was on Stack Overflow, I said its probably been answered before. Since its in JavaScript, I'd say use IF/ELSE and see which answer has been selected. Then redirect to another page. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Just check the "Go to page based on answer" option on the page of the form you want to set this for:

[image]

That lets you set the page to go to next to each option:

[image]

It sounds like you want to have multiple redirects based on two or more answers that are selected. In that case, you would just chain these together to reach the desired outcome.

For example, if they answer A, they'd go to a page for 1, 2, and 3. Then, based on their response, you'd have the outcomes of A1, A2, and A3. You'd do the same for B and C.

If you're okay with working with [Google Apps Script](//developer.google.com/apps-script), you might be able to create something a bit more coherent (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)).

Comment: Your example only shows one question.  I am able to do that easily.  But if the answers to two different questions have the "Got to page based on answer selected" it always goes to the next page based on one answer only.  Can you test your theory with two questions?

Comment: @CarrlosBoyd That's why I said to chain them together.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following you.

Comment: If user selects A, go to a page specifically for A that has 1, 2, and 3. Then, base answers on A1, A2, and A3. Do the same for the others: that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I can do that but with the length of my form, I'm trying to avoid having extra pages.